# "The process was done correctly" Confirm the correct steps have been taken

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

My question is if the sentence

> "the process was done correctly"

is grammatically correct and in a logical sequence of words that can be understood. I seems straight forward to me but I'm not sure it would to others.

Comment: It makes perfect sense and no-one would have any trouble understanding, but to my ear it sounds slightly awkward to use the fairly informal "done" with the formal "process" and "correctly".  If you need formality (e.g. for a written report) I would say "the process was *performed* correctly" instead.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Agreed, also "the process was *followed* correctly" (or the inverse word order, "correctly followed").

Comment: An even better version is "the process was executed (or implemented) properly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, the sentence tells us that someone or something did the process correctly, but it doesn't identify who or what that doer was. To introduce that information, you can either extend the current passive-voice construction:

> The process was done [or "performed" or "followed" or "implemented"] correctly by Mr. Big.

or you can rework the sentence in active voice:

> Mr. Big did [or "performed" or "followed" or "implemented"] the process correctly.